# ImportError: cannot import name 'patterns'

Tags: django

I have a problem with Django, I created a 'login' app and added the URL on mysite/urls.py as below:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, patterns, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^user-auth/', include('user_auth.urls')),
    url(r'^file-upload/', include('file_uploader.urls')),
    url(r'^pagination/', include('pagination.urls')),

    patterns('login.views',
    url(r'^login/', 'loginView'),
    url(r'^greeting/', 'formView'),
    url(r'^logout/', 'logoutView')
)   
]
```

However, when I started the server, I received the message on console as:

```
File "/home/win/Python/mysite/mysite/urls.py", line 16, in <module>
    from django.conf.urls import include, patterns, url
ImportError: cannot import name 'patterns'
```

Do you meet any problem like this? and any resolution do you have to resolve it.
Please please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried installing patterns exclusively? Use `pip install patterns` if not.

Comment: I did it Nikhil, but the error messege still displays. Thanks

Comment: Hue, if you insist on using 'patterns' , do note that if you do pip install patterns , you need to import from that library specifically.. i.e. do something like ....from patterns import pattern..... and add it to your django apps, since its third party lib. Even without knowing the details of the library, i'd advise against using it with django urls if you're new, just stick to the django way of doing things and get your idea off the ground.. You can see my answer below for helpful links.

Answer (score 6):

In the latest release of Django (as of this post), patterns is not used.

You can use `re_path` for the same effect. For Example:

```
from django.urls import include, re_path
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^admin', include(admin.site.urls)),
    re_path(r'^$', home, name='home'),
]
```

For more information please follow: [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#re-path)

Answer (score 3):

FYI *patterns* has been removed in Django 1.10. See release 1.10 notes:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/1.10/

If you want to use earlier versions (but i don't see why you would want to do it) , anything below that i.e. 1.9 should be ok, but do note it has been slotted for deprecation since 1.8 i think.

And if you're using django, especially if you are new, I don't see why you would want to use your own login app. Django has a very mature and customizable auth backend. For starters, I strongly suggest you check it out. Useful examples of usage at https://djangobook.com/authentication-views/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of Django, then patterns is has been deprecated. You would simply use URL and/or Path depending on if you are on 1.11 or 2.0. If you require patterns, then you would need to downgrade to an earlier Django version.

Comment: ,Thanks CoolestNerdIII,
I am using Django 2.0, Do you have any resolution on this?, please give me details your idea to resolve this problem. 
Thank you so much,